# How to pack a library using es2015 modules

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

Say I have created a library consisting of a bunch of es2015 module-files using the `export`-statement, how could I pack them together in one .js file in order to deliver the library? The es2015 modules should be preserved, so that a user of this library could still use `import`-statements to import the exported things.

i.e imagine there were two modules:

foo.js:

```
export default class Foo {...}
```

bar.js:

```
export default class Bar{...}
```

I would like to pack this together in ... lets say `magic-lib.js` and then us it like this:

using-magic-lib.js:

```
import Foo from 'magic-lib'
...
```

How could this be done?

Btw: I've tryed to pack my lib using rollup-js to one file, but I wasn't able to get a result that still uses `exports`. Apart from that, my favourite solution would be some vanilla-js...

Comment: *"Apart from that, my favourite solution would be some vanilla-js..."* JavaScript, the language, doesn't provide a way to bundle multiple files into a single one. You'll have to make use of third-party software one way or another.

Comment: I don't know the state of the art on bundlers well enough to feel comfortable answering this question. From an import/export perspective, you'd create a new module to group things together: `import Foo from './foo.js'; import Bar from './bar.js'; export { Foo, Bar };` and then if you wanted just `Foo` from the result, it would be `import { Foo } from './magic-lib.js';` That's fully-compatible with tree-shaking (e.g.,. a bundler or -- when this is native -- environment could avoid bundling/loading `Bar` if it were never used). But as to the bundler level of it...

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand the basic concept of modules in Javascript. In my understanding  a "module" is something bigger that bundles something together that itself consists of several smaller but distinct Units. These smaller Units could be classes or prototypes - in my understanding. And I would like to put each class in its own file. But then a class would be module... this doesn't fit together somehow...

Comment: Modules just formalizes code organization over multiple files. This was not something that was originally built into the language and several different approaches emerged over the years. It's perfectly fine to have a module only export a single class, if it makes within your library. In the end, how you organize your code is up to you.

Comment: And if you did do a class-per-file (nothing wrong with that, other than lots of individual files), you could do rollup modules of related classes, and then the final rollup could be a rollup-of-rollups. (And there's syntax that helps there; to export *all* named exports of a module from another module, you can use `export * from ...`.)

Comment: infact the rollups-of-rollups is what I was trying to do in my project, but in that concrete case I wasn't able to bundle a rollup together without loosing the `export`-Statements. I thought setting `format` to `es` in the rollup-config would do that, but it didn't (no `export`-Statements in the generated bundle). And using `amd` or `cjs` seems to be more a fallback for older JS-versions without using es6-modules...

Comment: @Felix Kling: I also understand modules to be something that organize code over multiple files. But in JS a single file seems to be called a "module", not a bunch of files...

Comment: @treeno Rollup with `options.format = es` should indeed work. Please post your attempt (some small example module files and your rollup config and invocation).

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, after I noticed that the plugin `rollup-plugin-multi-entry` doesn't preserve `export default` in the generated bundle, I was able to get that running by switching to non-default exports.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I am now able to bundle packages using rollup.js with `Options.format= 'es'` and the plugin `rollup-plugin-multi-entry`. My mistake was that I used `export default` and expected that this would work with more then one export in a single bundle-file. The rollup-plugin-mutliy-entry doesn't preserve them in the final bundle. But using non-default exports works.

So, viewed from a higher Level, I now have a single js-file for each module created by rollup.js. This module-js-file consists of several classes. Only those classes that are supposed to be used from outside of the library (public interface) are exported.

Addionally I bundle all module-js-files together in one big app-js-file (rollup of rollups) which is bundled with `options.format = 'iife'` and which is only intended to be used as the executable application bundle for a browser.

```
-Module-A.js 
 |- class InternalTool
 |- export class A 

-Module-B.js
-Module-C.js

-App.js
|- Module A
|- Module B
|- Module C
```

This way I'm able to create strongly separated and reusable modules that can be combined to an application.